# Meaning of ボロカスにされる

Tags: translation, meaning, slang, colloquial-language

I'm reading a manga and came across the following lines (in it A is talking to someone else about a third party C):

> A: バカめが!
>
> A: Cにボロカスにされるがいいわ！！

Most dictionaries I've looked at put ボロカス as a sort of harsh criticism/verbal attack but given that I'm still not entirely clear as to how it's being used in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

1) Meaning of 「ボロカスにする」(active voice) and 「ボロカスにされる」(passive voice).

2) Meaning of 「Verb Phrase + がいい」

I shall explain both, but if it still does not fit the context, you will need to provide the context.

「ボロカスにする」 means "to shoot down in flames" - verbally, that is.

「ボロカスにされる」, thus, naturally means "to be shot down in flames".

「Verb Phrase + がいい」 means "may as well (verb)", "had better (verb)", etc.

> 「Cにボロカスにされるがいいわ！！」

therefore, means:

> "You'd better get shot down in flames by C! "

In case anyone is wondering, 「ボロ」, all by itself, means "rags" and 「カス」, "dregs".